# error in website and recover my posts of my website

Tags: dns, information-extraction, public-html

[php error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0H7zq.png)
this runs on variant php script. but there some errors showing in my website. can you please help me.

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: 8192
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaA83.png)
and also wants to ask that can i transfer website prom php to wordpress plateform. if yes please guide

i tried but i am a non IT person. if someone guide or educate me.